# Google App Engine cron jobs fails and does not retry

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, cron

I have a simple cron.xml file that I use to run different jobs. I deploy it to app engine and it runs seamlessly for weeks. Everyone once in a while the cron fails with the error below. The weird part is that it does not retry, even though I have retry parameters.

I've also noticed that all subsequent cron jobs will fail until I redeploy my app.

The Error:

```
Process terminated because the request deadline was exceeded. (Error code 123)
```

The Cron.xml

```
<cron>
  <url>/conrurl</url>
  <description>Cron Description</description>
  <schedule>every 30 minutes from 06:00 to 22:00</schedule>
  <retry-parameters>
    <min-backoff-seconds>2.5</min-backoff-seconds>
    <max-doublings>5</max-doublings>
  </retry-parameters>
  <timezone>America/Montreal</timezone>
  <target>backend</target>
</cron>
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a HardDeadlineExceededError to me (see doc snippet and link below).

How long does the cron job take to run?  If I'm seeing deadline exceeded errors and timing information isn't available from another source I'll wrap my function with a basic timer to find out.  I don't write a lot of Java but here's an example: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/measure-time-taken-function-java/

From the [AppEngine documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deadlineexceedederrors#the-request-timer):

In the Java runtime, if the DeadlineExceededException is not caught, an uncatchable HardDeadlineExceededError is thrown. The instance is terminated in both cases, but the HardDeadlineExceededError does not give any time margin to return a custom response.

Comment: Cron job normally takes 400 seconds to run, when it failed, it was 82k seconds before it failed. Even then, I would expect it to re-try or run again on it's schedule, but it didn't.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.  Is it possible the error is being surfaced by something downstream?  Does the cron job interact with any other AppEngine services?  One place to look if you haven't already is the trace dashboard at http://cloud.google.com/console/traces/overview.  If you click on the cron handler you might be able to see where it's getting stuck.